# Should you always wear socks with roller skates/blades?

Tags: equipment, injuries, skating

This does not relate to rental equipment.

I have inline skates, because I noticed I was getting better and better at skating and wanted something I know would be comfortable and fitting. I notice they have a lot of padding inside, I'm assuming so you can make it very tight and snug and still have circulation. My question is, should it be okay to go 'foot commando' as it were, or would that be too rough on my skin and cause lots of blisters, or some other problem?

Comment: While this kind of question *may attract* more opinion-based answers than usual, people with experience in roller skating and/or expertise in skincare w.r.t. active sports would be able to give an answer which is at least as valid as a majority of answers elsewhere on Sports.SE. **However**, they should ideally refer to credible independent sources wherever possible and appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Generically speaking (rather than regarding you specifically), socks are optional.  Barefoot skating is a pretty common question in skating specific forums like https://www.fsuniverse.net/ or https://skatingforums.com or http://www.skatelogforum.com.  Skaters say they can feel the surface better and the grip is better especially with custom fitted boots.  There is the same risk for infections as there would be for other sporting gear and shoes that touch sweaty skin.  There is discussion that one's skates stink more if one skates barefoot, but I skate with socks (albeit real thin ones) and my skates stink pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

For myself, no socks mean blisters will happen. This is true for any sport where the shoe itself is subjected to sudden stops, twists, turns, and long-term use.

Answer (score 0):

I wear two pair of really thick high socks to have a better feel with my skates by strapping them extra tight at the same time. I like my skates really reactive and after some time I forget I have them on.

I wouldn't advice wearing none. Too much space around your feet and less overall feel with your boots in general. Blisters assured.